# Ads.txt not found - Adsense problem even though Ads.txt file is correct

Tags: javascript, html, ads, blogger, adsense

I have a small blogger blogspot website 1fakt-app.blogspot.com

I had this blog for years and i receive some revenue from it through Adsense.

A couple of days ago i received a warning : Earnings at risk - You need to fix some ads.txt file issues to avoid severe impact to your revenue.

Beside the fact that i did not change anything in my configuration i still copied and pasted the code of Ads.txt file from Adsense to my blog just to be sure i had the right Ads.txt file.

Nothing changed! When i go to 1fakt-app.blogspot.com/ads.txt the file is there.

Any ideas what might cause this problem?

Comment: Search for *You need to fix some ads.txt file issues to avoid severe impact to your revenue* on the internet.

Comment: did you try to amend your json file, as detailled here :https://sellers.guide/domain/1fakt-app.blogspot.com

Answer (score 0):

your ads.txt should be accessible with and without www
Your ads.txt is not accessible with www and it is not redirecting to  1fakt-app.blogspot.com/ads.txt So google crawler is not able to access your ads.txt file.In blogger setting make sure that it is redirecting to 1fakt-app.blogspot.com/ads.txt. And change your redirecting settings turn it on.

Answer (score 0):

I had a same problem you need to add ads.txt file in root directory even if you are using Ads Manager plugin to serve ads.txt file and if you are using sit Kit so please update that plugin too . Hopefully after a day your issue will resolved .